# Как получать X-Xsrf-Token и Cookies при регистрации?

Tags: javascript

```
    const axios = require('axios');

// Generate random email, password, and login
const randomEmail = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 12) + '@mail.ru';
const randomPassword = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 12);
const randomLogin = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 12);

// Data to send in the POST request
const postData = {
  email: randomEmail,
  password: randomPassword,
  login: randomLogin,
  info: {
    vendor: "Google Inc. (NVIDIA)",
    renderer: "ANGLE (NVIDIA, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)"
  }
};

// Axios POST request configuration
const axiosConfig = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://banter1.win/api/registr',
  data: postData,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://banter1.win',
    'Referer': 'https://banter1.win/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.31',
  }
};

// Send the POST request
axios(axiosConfig)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('Request sent successfully');
    console.log('Response data:', response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error sending request:', error);
  });
```

вот такой скрипт у меня есть, мне надо чтоб когда делался запрос не было ошибки
data: { message: 'CSRF token mismatch.' }

связана она с тем что я не передаю Cookie и X-Xsrf-Token
но когда я пытаюсь полученные ему выдавать та же самая ошибка

Comment: заходим на главную, получаем куки, переходим с полученными куками на регистрацию